# Identify plant with red spherical flowers with long hairy thin petals

Tags: identification, flowers

[image: red flower with long stamens]

Please help me identify this flower, I saw this in my garden in India

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an [*Albizia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albizia) or Silk Tree; note the pinnate leaf and the flower with very long stamens. This one happens to be pink in colour but there are other colours. There are many different Albizias so it will be a puzzle to try to distinguish which species. Some are considered weedy and invasive.